# Toilet straight water supply line stuck

Tags: plumbing, toilet

The water supply line is stuck and the nut is removed. It turns with some force but won't detach from the bottom of the tank

[image]

Comment: A photo would be very helpful.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: It is a straight pipe and I have loosed the nut to the valve and the top of the water line. I've tried moving it back and forth but it won't budge. it only turns with some force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That supply line should be disconnected at the shutoff valve as well and should then be fairly easy to bend and remove. The plastic nut at the base of the tank can then be removed to change out the fill valve.
You'll want to replace that supply line with a flexible line just a little longer than the distance from the shutoff valve to the base of the tank. If your shutoff valve is old and squirrely you might want to replace that as well with a ball and valve 1/4 turn.
**Edit**
Usually there's enough play up and down to remove the fixed supply line but some I've had to bend a little to remove. You'll probably want to replace it anyway.

Comment: The nut on the valve is disconnected but the line only rotates. Are you saying I should try to bend the line?

Comment: @Brian - you need to pull it out of the valve first. Loosen the nut all the way and slide it up a little. Push the valve down gently and pull up on the line (no bending required; especially if you're replacing with hard-line). Once free of the valve it should fall right out after a little tug. To replace with hard-line: do it in reverse order.